# Layout syntax of an Edit Field component in MATLAB App Designer in a grid parent

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I would like to specify the layout in a grid of an edit field as soon as I create it in MATLAB App Designer.

```
app.villes1 = uieditfield(app.GHIetPOA_grid, 'text', 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', ...
              'Editable', 'on', 'Layout', **???**);
```

I tried using simply [r,c] but this syntax does not seems right. I googled my problem an only founded ways to specify row and column by creating the edit field and specifying the row and column after by dot indexing :

```
app.villes1.Layout.Row = 2; 
app.villes1.Layout.Column = i+2;
```

However, I can't use this because I am actually generating edit field in a for loop and dot indexing is forbidden this way :

```
function initVilles1(app)
    for i=1:8
        app.villes1(i) = uieditfield(app.GHIetPOA_grid, 'text', 'HorizontalAlignment', ...
        'center', 'Editable', 'on');
        app.villes1(i).Layout.Row = 2; 
        app.villes1(i).Layout.Column = i+2; 
     end
end
```

Thanks already! (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `villes1` as array of `gobjects`.
See [Graphics Arrays](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/concatenating-handles-into-arrays.html).

Example:

```
properties (Access = private)
    GHIetPOA_grid  matlab.ui.container.GridLayout
    villes1 = gobjects(1, 8);
end
```

I can only guess that you used the following syntax: `villes1 = zeros(1, 8);`
Above syntax creates an array of `double` elements.
Then `app.villes1(i) = uieditfield(...)` creates an "old style" numeric handle, instead of creating an object.
Dot notation is forbidden when using numeric handles.

You need to use the following syntax instead: `villes1 = gobjects(1, 8);`.
Now the dot indexing should work.

---

Here is the complete code (include generated code):

```
classdef app1 < matlab.apps.AppBase

    % Properties that correspond to app components
    properties (Access = public)
        UIFigure  matlab.ui.Figure
    end


    properties (Access = private)
        Panel          matlab.ui.container.Panel
        GHIetPOA_grid  matlab.ui.container.GridLayout
        villes1 = gobjects(1, 8);
    end

    methods (Access = private)

        function initVilles1(app)
            for i=1:8
                app.villes1(i) = uieditfield(app.GHIetPOA_grid, 'text', 'HorizontalAlignment', ...
                'center', 'Editable', 'on');
                app.villes1(i).Layout.Row = 2; 
                app.villes1(i).Layout.Column = i+2; 
             end            
        end
    end


    % Callbacks that handle component events
    methods (Access = private)

        % Code that executes after component creation
        function startupFcn(app)
            % Create Panel
            app.Panel = uipanel(app.UIFigure);
            app.Panel.Title = 'Panel';
            app.Panel.Position = [42 198 1026 464];

            % Create GridLayout
            app.GHIetPOA_grid = uigridlayout(app.Panel);
            app.GHIetPOA_grid.RowHeight = {'1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x', '1x'};

            %app.villes1 = uieditfield(app.GHIetPOA_grid, 'text', 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center', 'Editable', 'on');
            initVilles1(app);
        end
    end

    % Component initialization
    methods (Access = private)

        % Create UIFigure and components
        function createComponents(app)

            % Create UIFigure and hide until all components are created
            app.UIFigure = uifigure('Visible', 'off');
            app.UIFigure.Position = [100 100 1118 692];
            app.UIFigure.Name = 'UI Figure';

            % Show the figure after all components are created
            app.UIFigure.Visible = 'on';
        end
    end

    % App creation and deletion
    methods (Access = public)

        % Construct app
        function app = app1

            % Create UIFigure and components
            createComponents(app)

            % Register the app with App Designer
            registerApp(app, app.UIFigure)

            % Execute the startup function
            runStartupFcn(app, @startupFcn)

            if nargout == 0
                clear app
            end
        end

        % Code that executes before app deletion
        function delete(app)

            % Delete UIFigure when app is deleted
            delete(app.UIFigure)
        end
    end
end
```

Remark: Next time you post a question, please make an effort to post all the relevant code.

Comment: You guessed correctly, I used the syntax: villes1 = zeros(1, 8);

Thank you so much! Works just how I wished now:D